# Passing Downloaded file from one fragment to another fragment when the file is fully downloaded

Tags: android, android-fragments, service, android-recyclerview, broadcastreceiver

I have two fragment, fragment_a and fragment_b under an activity, main activity. I download file from service that show on fragment_a in a queue. Now I want to send the Downloaded file from fragment_a to fragment_b when the file is fully downloaded in the queue. Please give me a demo example how I can implement it.
I am new in android programming.

Answer (score 0):

In Download Fragment pass data to arguments after image downloaded

```
String imagePath = downloadImageFile.getAbsolutePath();

Fragment2 obj_frament2 = new Fragment2();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("image_path", imagePath);
obj_frament2.setArguments(bundle);

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, obj_frament2).commit();
```

In Another Fragment get data from arguments

```
String imagePath = getArguments().getString("image_path");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new File(imagePath));
```